# Timestamp data value different between Hive tables and databricks delta tables

Tags: azure, hive, azure-databricks, delta-lake

We have done binary copy of data from Hive to ADLS with checksum validated. While values across every datatype matches however timestamp datatype columns are showing change in value between Hive and Delta(Azure Databricks) tables.

```
select abcdtstmp from  xyz.abc where mn_ID = "sdsdsd-7878-0016" 
2018-01-16 00:00:00.0 (on prem)
select abcdtstmp from  xyz.abc where mn_ID = "sdsdsd-7878-0016" 
2018-01-16T05:00:00.000+0000(DBX)
```

While checksum and all validation does match, however some values getting added after 'T' is causing concern. Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to `timezone` and hive.
Hive always thinks that timestamps in Parquet files are stored in UTC and it will convert them to a local system time (cluster host time) when it outputs. So, even if you are transferring data from EST to EST, its hive that is the culprit.

You can follow this link if you have hive version higher than 1.2 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9482
set `hive.parquet.timestamp.skip.conversion=true`
Else, you need to manually convert the data back to EST or whatever timezone you want using below sql.

```
from_utc_timestamp(to_utc_timestamp(my_dt_tm,'America/New_York'),'America/Denver') AS local_time
```

Comment: Thanks Koushik for this interpretation. If you see our issue, querying from Databricks delta table or previewing the parquet file in ADLS we only get the value as "2018-01-16T05:00:00.000+0000" and not "2018-01-16 00:00:00.0". While Databricks also leverages underlying Hive engine why is display in delta table not coming up with local timestamp (2018-01-16 00:00:00.0). This could have maintained the consistency in how Hive displays parquet file.

Comment: Difference between UTC and EST is 5 hours so you can see `T05:00:00.000` and what i answered is i think related to migration. we had this issue in hive sqooping but it may be different for you. You can check it out.